# best practice for generic interface and object orientation structure

Tags: c#, oop, generics, interface

I have an interface that has like 20 Properties that should be implemented all this properties should return an interface type or anything that inherits from this interface, each property of those 20 is returning a diffrent type than the other.

Is there a better way than doing the following?

```
    public interface IRepository<Product, ProductCategory, Category, ProductImage>
    where Product : IProduct
    where ProductCategory : IProductCategory
    where Category : ICategory
    where ProductImage : IProductImage
{
    IQueryable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    IQueryable<ProductCategory> Products { get; set; }
    IQueryable<Category> Products { get; set; }
    IQueryable<ProductImage> Products { get; set; }
}
```

i have briefed the code above to only have four generic types in the interface.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, one uses interfaces to avoid tying code to specific concrete types.

Why can you just write:

```
public interface IRepository
{    
    IQueryable<IProduct> Products { get; set; }
    IQueryable<IProductCategory> Products { get; set; }
    IQueryable<ICategory> Products { get; set; }
    IQueryable<IProductImage> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: because if i implemented this interface all properties should be an exact interface type, but not anything that implements it which is the main problem for me. thanks for trying.